# CSS link overlay not working in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, hyperlink

I have a DIV that is relatively positioned. The whole DIV needs to link to another page.

What I'm doing is adding a link inside the div and applying this CSS to it:

```
.f170region .linkcover {
    background: #FFF;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    hasLayout: true;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

What this does in all browsers other than IE6 is make the link act as a click-able layer over the DIV. The link also has an `.ir` class added to it to hide the text from inside the link off the screen:

```
.ir { display: block; text-indent: -999em; overflow: hidden; background-repeat: no-repeat; text-align: left; direction: ltr; }
```

Anyone got a solution to get this to work in IE6. And please don't give me the lecture about supporting IE6. I'm right there with you.

Here is the HTML that uses this method:

```
    <div class="alpha omega grid_4 f170region white" id="home_bg_youthzone">
        <h2 class="hidden">Youth Zone</h2>
        <div class="copy">There are many ways for younge residents to get help and support. Find out more...</div>
        <div class="getin">
            <p><span class="pink">Get</span><br />involved</p>
            <p><span class="pink">Get</span><br />in the zone</p>
        </div>
        <a class="linkcover ir" href="<?php echo site_url("/youth-zone/"); ?>" title="Go to Youth Zone">Go to Youth Zone</a>
    </div>
```

EDIT 2:

http://jsfiddle.net/9gSUd/

Comment: is the `div` nested inside the `a`? If so, please note that this is invalid in many doctypes including HTML 4 and XHTML 1.x

Comment: @Bazzz no its the other way around. the `<a>` is inside the `<div>`.

Comment: Can you add your HTML? It might help finding the right solution.

Comment: can you post a fiddle , jsfiddle.net ? And yea , if you do need to support IE6 , you may want to check this link http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution using a spacer.gif file as the BG. I was using this fix to make the overlay work properly in IE http://kevindees.cc/2011/01/ie-adjacent-positioning-image-and-link-overlap-css-fix/

This would set the BG to white but set the opacity to 0. This worked in all version of IE but IE6. By setting the background to a spacer.gif instead of white and setting the width/height of the link to 100% I got a working solution in IE6 and all browsers. Here is my final CSS for the link:

```
.f170region .linkcover {
    background: url(../images/spacer.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Maybe so but its fixed my issue. Last time I used spacer.gif was when doing templates with tables over 6 years ago :)

Comment: `filter: alpha(opacity=n)` makes IE to ignore `height: 100%`. Setting background might be solution.

Answer (score -1):

Setting the anchor to display `block` and with a `width` and `height` of `100%` should work even in IE6.

```
div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid green;
}

a{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Kkjdw/

**UPDATE**

Given the requirement that the anchor covers all content currently in the div, here's an updated example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kkjdw/1/

Comment: This wont work as it needs to appear over the top of the content thats already in the div.

Comment: Here's an update that also includes this requirement: http://jsfiddle.net/Kkjdw/1/

Comment: This works but breaks the other IE fix of applying BG colour and setting transparency in IE6

Comment: The original answer was wrong and your update still doesn't work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kkjdw/6/ I've been able to replicate IE6 issue here with the CSS I have.